# Remove designated waterprints made by eso-pic

Tags: watermark, eso-pic, xwatermark

I construct four waterprints by `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` from package `eso-pic` as the following code shows.

Then I want to remove `waterpint-1` and `waterprint-2` from page 3. I know `\ClearShipoutPictureBG` can clears the contents made by `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`, but this macro will clear all.

So my question is: how to remove designated waterprints made by eso-pic? Is there a way, for example, give each waterprint a name, then remove the waterprint by name? Like this:

```
\waterprinton{name1,name2}  
add waterprint here
...
other content
...
\waterprintoff{name1,name2}
```

CODE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture,color}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtTextUpperLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-1}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtTextLowerLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-2}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-3}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-4}}}
fist page
\clearpage
second page
\clearpage
third page
\clearpage
fourth page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\ClearShipoutPictureBG ` on the third page, and the four adds again on the fourth page.

Comment: Thank you. I think it''s boring to repeat(copy) the same code again especially when there are many such thing need to be repeated. This is why I ask for help.

Comment: You can program it: `if page=n then....`.

Comment: In a long article, the exact page number maybe not forseen. I updated my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a command or a boolean

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,color,etoolbox}
\newcommand\lylI{\AtTextUpperLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-1}}}
\newbool{lylshow}
\booltrue{lylshow}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\lylI}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifbool{lylshow}{\AtTextLowerLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-2}}}{}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-3}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{\parbox{12em}{waterprint-4}}}
fist page
\clearpage
\boolfalse{lylshow}
second page
\clearpage
\booltrue{lylshow}
third page
\renewcommand\lylI{}

\clearpage
fourth page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thank you for this solution! And I updated my query. Would you please have a glance at it? Thank you.

Comment: well simply use more booleans and then define your command so that it switches them on and off.